# How to translate text from one language to another language android?

Tags: android, google-translate, machine-translation

I have a response which I parse from json and displayed the result. Is it possible to convert to other language like French, Hindi, German?

When I browsed, I came to know google stopped on 2011 as free version and started pricing. Is there any free version to convert the response text to other language?

Piece of code is as follows:

```
  TextView text; // created an id.

  JSONObject jsono=new JSONObject(data);
  JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("posts");
  for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
   JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
  String name= object.getString("name");
  text.setText(name);// how to convert this to other language.
```

Say for eg: response what I get is Good morning. which I need to translate and display in textview as Bonjour which is in French.

Comment: Check using Google Translate API. I've never used it in my code.I think it might help you.

Comment: but it as mentioned as price. @Amrut

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a detailed [blog post](http://elsoufy.blogspot.fr/2012/07/using-speech-input-api.html) on using different translation services on an Android app. The source code is on [github](https://github.com/dzlab/DroidTranslator) with a sample of using [MyMemory service](https://github.com/dzlab/DroidTranslator/blob/master/src/org/soufy/translator/TranslationActivity.java#L155-L172) for translation.

```
/** Translate a given text between a source and a destination language */
public String translate(String text) {      
    String translated = null;
    try {
        String query = URLEncoder.encode(text, "UTF-8");
        String langpair = URLEncoder.encode(srcLanguage.getLanguage()+"|"+dstLanguage.getLanguage(), "UTF-8");
        String url = "http://mymemory.translated.net/api/get?q="+query+"&langpair="+langpair;
        HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();                 
        HttpGet hg = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse hr = hc.execute(hg);
        if(hr.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {                
            JSONObject response = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(hr.getEntity()));
            translated = response.getJSONObject("responseData").getString("translatedText");                
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    return translated;      
}
```

Comment: How can I download this?

Comment: @AAShakil download what?

Comment: How to download translation packages in .db format.

Comment: {"responseData":{"translatedText":"INVALID LANGUAGE PAIR SPECIFIED. EXAMPLE: LANGPAIR=EN|IT USING 2 LETTER ISO OR RFC3066 LIKE ZH-CN. ALMOST ALL LANGUAGES SUPPORTED BUT SOME MAY HAVE NO CONTENT"},"quotaFinished":null,"responseDetails":"INVALID LANGUAGE PAIR SPECIFIED. EXAMPLE: LANGPAIR=EN|IT USING 2 LETTER ISO OR RFC3066 LIKE ZH-CN. ALMOST ALL LANGUAGES SUPPORTED BUT SOME MAY HAVE NO CONTENT","responseStatus":"403","responderId":null,"exception_code":null,"matches":""}

Answer (score 1):

Text translation between languages can be done using Firebase ML kit translator api. Input to the api is text to be translated and source and target languages.
The api downloads the source and target language models if not available on the device and performs the translation. You can find complete android example here. https://www.zoftino.com/android-translate-text-example

```
FirebaseTranslatorOptions options =
        new FirebaseTranslatorOptions.Builder()
                .setSourceLanguage(FirebaseTranslateLanguage.ES)
                .setTargetLanguage(FirebaseTranslateLanguage.EN)
                .build();
FirebaseTranslator Translator =
        FirebaseNaturalLanguage.getInstance().getTranslator(options);

translator.translate(inputText)
      .addOnSuccessListener(
          new OnSuccessListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(@NonNull String translatedText) {

            }
          })
      .addOnFailureListener(
          new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

            }
     });
```